# Extract hostvar list

Tags: ansible, hostvars

I'm trying to get secondary ip addresses from hosts in a group and set them to a fact.

my hostvars contain

```json
{
  "network_interfaces": [
    {
      "private_ip_address": "10.224.1.48",
      "private_ip_addresses": [
        {
          "primary": true,
          "private_dns_name": "ip-10-224-1-48.us-east-2.compute.internal",
          "private_ip_address": "10.224.1.48"
        },
        {
          "primary": false,
          "private_dns_name": "ip-10-224-1-66.us-east-2.compute.internal",
          "private_ip_address": "10.224.1.66"
        },
        {
          "primary": false,
          "private_dns_name": "ip-10-224-1-135.us-east-2.compute.internal",
          "private_ip_address": "10.224.1.135"
        }
      ],
      "source_dest_check": true,
      "status": "in-use",
      "subnet_id": "subnet-0cfc6e2da31b9cf50",
      "vpc_id": "vpc-123456"
    }
  ],
}
```

Something like

```yaml
set_fact:
  private_ips: "{{ groups['database'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['network_interfaces[0]','private_ip_addresses[1]','private_ip_address']) | join(',')  }}"
```

which doesn't work.

```yaml
set_fact: 
  private_ips: "{{ groups['database'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['network_interfaces']) | map(attribute='private_ip_addresses') }}"
```

ends up with `"private_ips": "[AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined]"`

I'm looking for the result to be just a single IP out of private_ip_addresses from each host in the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the list of IPs at each host

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_ip: "{{ network_interfaces|json_query(_query) }}"
      vars:
        _query: '[].private_ip_addresses[].private_ip_address'
```

gives for the data from the example

```yaml
  my_ip:
  - 10.224.1.48
  - 10.224.1.66
  - 10.224.1.135
```

Then, select the second item from the lists of all hosts in the group *database*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        private_ips: "{{ groups.database|
                         map('extract', hostvars, 'my_ip')|
                         map(attribute=1)|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks.